# Show/hide text in MVC app

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app that uses the bootstrap responsive CSS. In the app I have a view that shows zero to many rows, like so:

```
@model List<SearchItem>

<section>
    @foreach (SeachItem searchitem in @Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("Searchitem", searchitem)
    }
</section>
```

In SearchItem a lot of fields are presented. (I should probably make a view for every field, but that's another issue). Like so:

```
foreach (string descShort in descriptions)
{
     <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2">@header</div>
          <div class="span10">@descShort</div>
     </div>
}
```

Sometimes these "description" fields are really long and then I choose to only present the first 20 characters. But I want the user to have the option to see the entire field if she wants to. I have two fields: descLong and descShort, and right now I'm only showing descShort (the shortened field). But with the click of the mouse I want to hide the descShort field and show the descLong instead.

So I'm planning on doing something like this:

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-show-and-hide-example/

But I'm having some problems with that approach since I theoretically can have hundreds of thousands of fields that should be hideable/showable, and not just one ("p") as in the example.

**So, what is my best approach to this?**

Should I put every "description" in its own view and pass the descShort and descLong to that view? And if so, how do I pass the two strings to that view and can I then put the jQuery example in that view and call the show/hide field "<p>" and it will work even though I might have thousands of fields called "<p>" once the entire page is rendered?

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Theoretically, hundreds or thousands of items in a single page is a bad performance, maybe pagination can do better. However, have you tried the solution, whether the solution is really perform bad or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm opting for the "is there a better way" option. My suggestion is to use CSS to limit the displayed text, and switch between the full and short version using a simple toggle of a CSS class:

Here is my example, you can [see it working on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fapAc/):

*HTML*

```
<div class="description">
    Imagine some really long description here. It is really long. Imagine some really long description here. It is really long. Imagine some really long description here. It is really long. Imagine some really long description here. It is really long. Imagine some really long description here. It is really long. 
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.description {
    height: 2.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.full {
    height: auto;
}
```

*jQuery*

```
$('.description').click( function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('full'); 
});
```

You could extend this example to show a visible indicator that the user can take action to see more - or you could do it on hover etc - this is just the concept.

Comment: That seems very promising. If I want to show the first 20 characters and the last 20 characters of the description, how would you suggest I go about that?